# Python and Quickbooks API

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I am wondering if someone has sample code of a working python connection to the Quickbooks API.   From the documentation of Intuit-Oaut, Python-Intuit, or intuit developer docs I cant figure out how to connect.   Would like to connect and then post sample JSON (for example a sales receipt), but cant seem to connect.

I am new to python and new to quickbooks api so apologies if this seems basic or am missing a step.

Followed steps on:
-https://oauth-pythonclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#authorize-your-app

-https://github.com/intuit/oauth-pythonclient

-https://github.com/sidecars/python-quickbooks

-https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization

Comment: Please provide a sample of code and problems that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [fo_qbo repo](https://github.com/finoptimal/fo_qbo). You need an Intuit developer account and (perhaps obviously but for the avoidance of doubt, Admin-level access to a QBO comapny instance) to use it.